# I am using tabulator, what could be causing the data to not appear in columns?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabulator

My data shows up like this. The data there is, and allows for sorting by column, but shows in one long line, with no vertical columns. I believe

[image]

Here are my index.js and my HTML.
I am very lost.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
//import 'tabulator-tables';
/*
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
*/
var Tabulator = require('tabulator-tables');

var tabledata = [
    { id: 1, name: "Billy Bob", age: 12},
    { id: 2, name: "Jenny Jane", age: 42 },
    { id: 3, name: "Steve McAlistaire", age: 35 },
];


//define table
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data: tabledata,
    autoColumns: true,
   // columns: [{ title: "Name", field: "name" },
        //{ title: "Age", field: "age" }  ]
});
table.setData(tabledata);


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
    <link href="dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
    <title>Metric React test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    
    <div id="example-table"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be better if you could share your code in a JS Fiddle or Code Pen, that way we could see the result rather than just having a picture to work off, without seeing the whole table it is difficult to diagnose an issue

Comment: on a side note there is no need to call the `setData` function if you are passing the data into the `data` property on the constructor, they do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you are missing the CSS for the table.

The link to the stylesheet looks wrong `dist/css/tabulator.min.css` would point to a dist folder relative to the current page which would be an odd place to store the file. It should be a path relative to the site root.

Also there is no need to include a script tag to `tabulator.js` in your HTML if you are importing it using an `import` statement in your JS

Comment: Where is the link to the code pen, could you include it in your question